# Replace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware and use exception handling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently, our ASP.NET Core 3.1 web api's error handling sends everything to our error controller using `app.UseExceptionHandling('/error')`. This controller logs the error and sends the error response our clients expect. Unfortunately, our logs contain each error twice because `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` logs the error before our error controller. How can we completely remove/replace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` such that we (a) log the error only once and (b) completely replaces the response with our content?

We decided to use `app.UseExceptionHandling('/error')` over `app.Use<CustomMiddlewareErrorHandler>()` because changing the content in middleware always produced the "response already started" error that we never see when we use the error controller. I've found tutorials that advice testing whether the response has already started, but we always want to replace it. I suppose we need to flush the response or something like that.

Can someone point me to a practical example that (a) prevents double logging and (b) allows me to completely replace the response after an error?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware source? Looks like it throws if response already started but otherwise performs some clearing of the context/response before moving on and forwarding to the exception "subpipeline". https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/5e575a3e64254932c1fd4937041a4e7426afcde4/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs You can create your own Middleware modeled after this with logging removed and use it instead if the one provided by UseExceptionHaner

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks. Why not make “use the original” a formal answer to “a practical example” so I can upvote and accept that?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the default and noisy "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware" adding this filter:

`LoggingBuilder.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware", LogLevel.None);`

And customizing your exception handler as you want.

Refs:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19740
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42950
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging